# Floating backgrounds with different height nicely

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a bunch of floating dynamic divs with different heights.
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g4o8rukz/)

I want to float the divs nicely, so in the example 14,15,16 should come before 10, and then 17,18,19 should come after.
Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Thanks :)

```
.blankspot div {
  float: left;
  border-right: solid 1px #fff;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #fed;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

EDIT:
Sorry, can see my description is a bit off.
[Here's a pic of what I want to achieve](http://screencast.com/t/s8UqayZaM)

My own research on this issue, tells me that a solution to the problem would result in third party code or some nasty ninja tricks.

Comment: Can you post an image of what exactly should the output be?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you here.  Under what circumstances do you want to move box 10 between box 16 and box 17?  Also, what screen width are you talking about?  How many boxes in a single row do you expect to have?

Comment: Dynamically calculating how to arrange things so as not to have the awkward gaps is a fairly involved process--a lot more than somebody here will do for you from scratch. However, this has become a fairly common task since card layouts have become the rage, and several third-party solutions have been created. Mason.js is one good one; Isotope, Masonry, and Packery are also worth considering. I'd check several out of these out and see if one of them needs your needs.

Comment: @user1026083 did you get anywhere with this in the end?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, like in your picture, you can control the width of the outer div to enclose 7 boxes per row then you can mess about with the margins to get the boxes to flow more neatly.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g4o8rukz/3/

The reason you need to know the number of boxes per row is because you need to know which box will need shifting in the row below.  If box 10 is selected to double in size then it's box 15 in the row below that needs dynamically updating with the class `neighbourBelow` in order to push its neighbours across in the same row.

You need to apply this +5 offset with JavaScript so you could number your boxes with something like this:

```
<label data-index="10">
   <div>10</div>
</label>
```

Then it's `selectedBox.attr('data-index') + 5` to determine the `data-index` of the box that needs its margin adjusting.  This is jQuery syntax but I'm sure you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Make the following change and your highlight box will fit the parent

```
width: 100px;
height: 50px;
background-color: #f0a;
```

I am not still clear what you wanted to tell regarding before after. If you want to appear 10 after 15 then move the rearrange just your divs. Something like the jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/johirbuet/g4o8rukz/2/

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP wants, as the title says *different height*.